# 32-bit AS number. Where can it be tricky?

Tags: bgp, as-number

Can 32-bit ASN be dangerous/tricky in any way? We are currently implanting BGP in our network. One of the uplinks has emphasized that their ASN is 32-bit. Ours is 32-bits as well. What is it I should be paying attention to when dealing with 32-bit ASNs? I've already checked that our router's software supports it. Is there anything else to be checked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

32-bit ASNs are backwards compatible with 16-bit ASNs, and if you have a proper BGP
implementation on your router 32-bit ASNs will be transported silently across your network. So  16-bit ASN routers do work with 32-bit routers and vice versa.

Where this would be tricky is a good question actually, since most of BGP just forwards stuff if there are new flags etc. that were introduced. The obvious issue would be broken implementations or non-standards behavior.